# Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle' in /app/AppKernel.php

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am new to Symfony.
Trying to install sonata admin bundle.
form:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/installation.html

But I got an error at
Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/AppKernel.php

My **AppKernel.php's code** is

```
     use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
     use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

     class AppKernel extends Kernel
   {
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = [
        new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
        new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
        new AppBundle\AppBundle(), 
        new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),

        // These are the other bundles the SonataAdminBundle relies on
        new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
        new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

        // And finally, the storage and SonataAdminBundle
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
    ];

    if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }

    return $bundles;
}

public function getRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__;
}

public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
}

public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

}

like this
and **composer.json's code is**

```
    {
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "3.1-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in Advance:

Comment: Your composer update has no error ? Does this bundle is well in your vendors folder ?

Comment: yes it is in vendors folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss requiring the bundle in composer...

try run

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
```

and composer install / update

From the sonata-admin documentation:

> SonataAdminBundle is storage agnostic, meaning it can work with several storage mechanisms. Depending on which you are using on your project, you’ll need to install one of the following bundles. In the respective links you’ll find simple installation instructions for each of them:

More here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/installation.html

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Edu for your Answer but when I run that commend to install doctrine-orm-admin-bundle  it gives me error of  **Trying to register two bundles with the same name "SecurityBundle" **

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was exactly as the error had said, the line

```
new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
```

was repeated twice in AppKernel.php